# grab active element after button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have Carousel on a page with the below structure:

```
<div class="my-controls">
  <button class="button123">
    <span class="abc">Next-image</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="my-carousel">                        
  <div class="item active">image1</div>                       
  <div class="item">image2</div>
  <div class="item">image3</div>
</div>
```

There is a button on the same page when clicked i need to grab the **active** element.

I tried something like this but the issue i'm seeing is that the class active is being added/changed AFTER the button event is triggered, so it is not giving me expected div element:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".button123").click(function(){
    var activeElement = $(".my-carousel .active")
    //do something with activeElement
});
});
```

Please let me know how I can grab the active element once it is changed.

Comment: We'll need more code. Does clicking the button do something like advance the carousel? At what point does your code add/remove the active class?

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: clicking the button advances the carousel and adds the class name to active to appropriate carousel. Added more info.

Comment: Why don't you add the code for advancing the carousel etc.?

Comment: I don't have access to that part of the code since it is coming from external library. else I would have added this logic in that code once the class is changed to active.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the new active element before the active class is on that element. Therefore, you want to figure out what element the active class will be on.

The answer depends on the carousel. If it just goes through all the items one way, without looping, you can just "stay one ahead" using jQuery's `.next()` method:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".button123").click(function(){

    if ($(".my-carousel .active").next().length) {
      // There is a next item, set activeElement to it
      var activeElement = $(".my-carousel .active").next()
    }

    // Do something with activeElement
  });
});
```

If the carousel loops, you can add an `else` statement which resets the carousel to the first item if there is no `.next()` child:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".button123").click(function(){

    if ($(".my-carousel .active").next().length) {
      // There is a next item, set activeElement to it
      var activeElement = $(".my-carousel .active").next()
    } else {
      // There is no next item, start from the beginning
      var activeElement = $(".my-carousel .active").siblings(":first-child")
    }

    // Do something with activeElement
  });
});
```

If the carousel can also move in both directions, you would have to hook up another button, one that scrolls backwards. Copy the click function, replace `.next()` with `.prev()` and that's it!

Here is a CodePen for a carousel that loops and moves in both directions: https://codepen.io/PXJesse/pen/YzwzgQR

Comment: The active class is changed on click of the same button. on first load I can grab the active element because on initial load the class is already set.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally misread your question. I updated my answer, hope it helps! Quick disclaimer though, I would highly recommend finding a way to run the code after the active class has changed so you can just select it with `$(".my-carousel .active")`. My answer above is functional, but hacky.